# Group by multiple columns : SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate

I have a table :

[image]

I have a query which gives me

[image]

And I want something like this :

[image]

Query used for above result is :

```
select ucountry,sum(Males) Males,sum(females ) Females from (
                                                  select ucountry,
                                                         case when gender = 'M' then count(1) else 0 end as Males,
                                                         case when gender = 'F' then count(1) else 0 end as females
                                                  from testing.test_users
                                                  group by ucountry, gender
                                              ) a group by ucountry;
```

I am definitely not doing the best thing here. Any thing you guys think would be better?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to count the number of males and females in each country:

```
select ucountry,
sum(case when gender = 'M' then 1 else 0 end) as males,
sum(case when gender = 'F' then 1 else 0 end) as females
from testing.test_users
group by ucountry
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **PostgreSQL** then you can also user `FILTER`

```
select ucountry, COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE gender = 'M') males, 
COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE gender = 'F') females from testing.test_users group by ucountry
```

Comment: Sorry @jarlh sir. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should apply **GROUP BY** only on **ucountry** column. Use below query to get expected result in **SQL Server**:

```
SELECT  
    ucountry, 
    SUM(IIF(Name = 'M', 1, 0)) males,
    SUM(IIF(Name = 'F', 1, 0)) females
FROM testing.test_users
GROUP BY ucountry
```